# mozilla doesnt interpret javascript well

Tags: javascript, html

I started recently learning javascript im stuck at the very beginning here is the problem

this is my code:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Chapter 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Here’s another basic page</h1>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
alert('Hello world!!');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and that's what the navigator shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/effM2.png)

Mozilla add some caracteres even in the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMg90.png)

PS: im using ubuntu, mozilla

Comment: You're using the wrong quotes.

Comment: The quotes are incorrect. You have some weird ones. You need to use `"`, `'` or none at all.

Comment: Ah, the risk of cut'n'paste coding and the nasty propensity of some text editing tools to ”beautify” quotes.

Comment: You should specify the encoding/charset in order to avoid the bad interpretation of your `h1` tag content characters

Comment: If you're using a word processor to write code, don't. It has a bad habit of doing things like this.

Comment: Make sure you are using a code editor or plain-text editor to code. Some word processors apply formating and change the type of quotation mark, they look the same but have different unicode values and won't play nice with browsers.

Comment: @NathanK I think certain blogging/CMS platforms might also do the same nastiness. I've copied stuff from the web with the same sorts of issues.

Comment: @IsmaelMigue thank you, that's exactly the solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Chapter 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Here's another basic page</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Hello world!!');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

U should be careful about syntax such as " "

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it help?

Answer (score 1):

You have two unrelated problems here.

## The JavaScript not running

HTML attribute values can be delimited with `U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK` or `U+0027 : APOSTROPHE`. Under some circumstances you can omit the delimiters entirely.

You are attempting to delimit the attribute value with `U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`, which isn't a valid delimiting character. Consequently it is being treated as if you weren't using delimiters and the `U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` at each end are part of the data.

While `text/javascript` is a recognised MIME type for JavaScript, `”text/javascript”` is not. Firefox is therefore (correctly) treated the script as if it was written in a language it does not understand and ignored it.

The type attribute was made optional with the publication of HTML 5. Omit it entirely to solve that problem.

## The header rendering incorrectly.

You have used a `U+2019 : RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` instead of a `U+0027 : APOSTROPHE`. On top of that, you have saved your document using one character encoding (maybe the legacy ISO-8859-1) but the browser it parsing it as a different encoding (maybe the modern UTF-8).

You should configure your editor to use UTF-8 and make sure that you tell the browser you are using UTF-8. The [W3C provide some introductory material on the subject](https://www.w3.org/International/getting-started/characters).